# How to escape "&" ampersand character in form input using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my jQuery script that send data via POST method. The problem is whenever it sends data via Ajax that has an "&" ampersand in the sentence, it will cut the sentence when found "&".

Please check the images below for more info.

[image: The text that pass to ajax POST]
[image: Output after ajax POST on firebug]
[image: Data that has been save in the database]
[image: The jQuery ajax POST]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[htmlentites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

> This function is identical to [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)() in all ways, except with [htmlentites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.
>
> If you're wanting to decode instead (the reverse) you can use [html_entity_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)().

Example:

```
echo htmlentities("&"); // &amp;
```

if your directly doing this in the browser you should be able to use:

```
encodeURIComponent(string input);
```

Example:

```
encodeURIComponent($.trim($("input[name=t-tim_rendered-"+id+"]").val().toString()));
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been having a huge problem exactly with this situation.

This is just to say that the last answer from Andrew Koester is the perfect answer I was looking for.

In case you are passing multiple form entries from a jQuery form to PHP through the .ajax() call like this:

data: "name=" + name + "&message=" + message + ...

DON'T USE THIS METHOD, it will block the ampersand(&) character from being written by the user on any of the input fields of your form.

Use this one instead as suggested by Andrew:

data: {"name": name, "email": email, "subject": subject, "comments": comments},

This way the user can write any kind of special character whithout worrying a about conflicting with the ajax declaration.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a native javascript escape() function

In line 74

```
data: : "&task_d=" + escape(task_d) + ""
```

Alternatively, you could enclose your query string values in quotes

```
data: : "&task_d='" + task_d + "'"
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, that was similar to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass your `data` parameter as a Javascript object, it will convert the characters for you (and IMO make the code look neater). So you should change your $.ajax call to the following:

```
data: {"user_id": user_id, "time_r": time_r, "task_d": task_d, "p_id": p_id, "df": finished},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'encodeURIComponent' to accomplish the URL encoding for that component. I used this and validated with browsers IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: The question is really old and this isn't contributing anything new to solve the problem. You should consider writing a comment instead, or just up-voting when you will be allowed to.